# What does one of the icons mean on the manual included with a Pi?

Tags: pi-4

What does this icon mean? (2 row, 2 column):

[image]

Comment: do what icon 1 tells you to do ... it may answer your question

Comment: Maybe they should have English subtitles on the hieroglyphics. I never learned to read hieroglyphics at school.

Comment: I hate it when user manuals are in vague pictures only. If they’d add at least English, Chinese and Russian subtitles it would make things so much clearer for ~95% of users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a guess, I'd think it means "Position board with the chips up."

Comment: That would be my guess.

Comment: but the network/hdmi connectors are clearly on top in that picture, so  the inset picture showing the chips seems unnecessary?

Comment: I did say it was a guess, but I can't imagine what else it might mean. Can you?